# This Javascript function I have bound to an HTML button isn't running at all

Tags: javascript, html

The clear() function in this code is not running when I press the "C" button (i.e. it isn't even printing to console) even though all the other buttons work fine. I'm sure I've missed something obvious but I cannot see it. Please help me find it:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var total = 0;
  function add(x) {
   total += x;
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  }
  function clear() {
   console.log('cleared');
   var total = 0;
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="total">0</p>
  <p>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(1)">1</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(2)">2</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(3)">3</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(4)">4</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(5)">5</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(6)">6</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(7)">7</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(8)">8</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(9)">9</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="clear()">C</button>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you are creating a new argument var total = 0; inside the clear() function.  Just take the `var` word out so you reference the existing original `total` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.document.clear` is Native API hence `function clear()` is shadowed, Use some other function name.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;

    function add(x) {
      total += x;
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
    }

    function clearVal() {
      console.log('cleared');
      total = 0;
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="total">0</p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(1)">1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(2)">2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(3)">3</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(4)">4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(5)">5</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(6)">6</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(7)">7</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(8)">8</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="add(9)">9</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearVal()">C</button>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** You are initializing variable `total` in `clearVal` function, not redefining it as `0`, remove keyword `var` to update global variable.

Comment: Wow thanks. I didn't even think of that. I though if any function would already be defined it would be add(x) so I just glossed over clear. I appreciate the quick response

Comment: Notice the other mistake being declaring `var total = 0;` inside of `clearVal()` instead of just overwriting `total = 0;`...

Comment: Yeah I think that was just something I tried in my desperation. Thanks! All fixed.

Answer (score 3):

**Not suggested but hacked way to do it and freaking cooool:**

> window.document.clear is Native API hence function clear() is shadowed
>
> But if you still want to keep the clear function name, you can also
>   override the `window.document.clear` a function like shown below.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var total = 0;
  function add(x) {
   total += x;
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  }
  window.document.clear = function() {
   console.log('cleared');
   total = 0;
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;
  };
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="total">0</p>
  <p>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(1)">1</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(2)">2</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(3)">3</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(4)">4</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(5)">5</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(6)">6</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(7)">7</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(8)">8</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="add(9)">9</button><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="clear()">C</button>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow , looks like its working and I was not aware that we can also override the default functions also.